# NSDateFormatter formats wrong for timezone

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, timezone, format

I have a problem with Date Format

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZZ"];
formatedDate =[format stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
```

Everything works fine, except one thing 
when I set the YEAR less than or equal to 1924, DateFormatter returns

```
1924-04-21 03:00:07+050748
```

Whereas should be

```
1924-04-21 03:00:07+0500
```

What's wrong?

Comment: can please tell me what is your input and expected output?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set your Timezone, like with GMT,

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZZ"];
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[format setTimeZone:gmt];
formatedDate =[format stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
```

This may change your time in output string `formatedDate`, but you can set `NSTimeZone` as per your requirement.

Comment: Do not use `YYYY` for the year, use `yyyy`.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the  Apple Data Formatting Guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html 
In the "Fixed Formats",
There are two things to note about this example:

It uses yyyy to specify the year component. A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the calendar year.
The representation of the time may be 13:00. In iOS, however, if the user has switched 24-Hour Time to Off, the time may be 1:00 pm.

So you should change "YYYY" to "yyyy".

Answer (score 0):

User this method .......

```
-(NSString*) currentDateForServer 
 {
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:UTC];
   [dateFormat setTimeZone:timeZone];
   [dateFormat setDateFormat:DATE_FORMATE];
   NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
   NSString *finalString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:currentDate];
   return finalString;
}
```

- Define UTC and DATE_FORMATE as you need